# Meal Plan Optimization Violating Constraints (Python, OR-Tools, Linear Programming, XLRD)

Tags: python, linear-programming, xlrd, or-tools

I've made a program to create meal plans that fulfill the recommended nutritional intake. I've gotten it to run, but it's giving results that violate the constraints, and I'm not sure why. How would I ensure the output stays within the necessary constraints? Any help would be appreciated.

Code and Spreadsheets: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kMAmUPQBP_mmKnAkQxnUft-EzufRuPRE

Comment: You need to put your code here and not behind a link, which forces users to go off-site. Links can also break. And if your code is too long, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In fact, do this regardless.

Comment: It would also be helpful after posting a minimal executable example (e.g. python code only) if you would state exactly which constraints are not being fulfilled, and for which input data.

Comment: Your problem is probably that you have not added any constraints to compute the total weight or price. The code section `for i in range(sheet.ncols): 
        price[i] = price[i] / 100 * weight[i]
    totalPrice = sum(price)` is computing local python variables, not creating constraints.  You will need to do something like make an integer "pricePerPound" array and then `solver.Add(price[i] == pricePerPound[i] * weight[i])`, and another one to constraint `totalPrice` to be the sum of the `price[]` variables.  You'll also need to have a constraint on the total weight and limit its domain.